# Creating a podspec with multiple targets which have local dependencies

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, podspec

- I have a podspec for MyLib.
- MyLib.xcworkspace has two targets: a MyLib target and a MySubLib target.
- MyLib depends on MySubLib.
- Both MyLib and MySubLib should be `import`able in a swift module using `MyLib` Cocoapod.

Illustration:

MyLib.xcworkspace

- MyLib target <---depends on---MySubLib

  - MyLib pods dependencies
- MySubLib target

How do we achieve this?

I have the following podspec but upon linting MySubLib is not found where it's `import`ed in MyLib.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "MyLib"
  s.version          = "0.1"
  s.summary          = ""

  s.description      = <<-DESC

                       DESC

  s.homepage         = "https://github.com/me/MyLib"
  s.license          = 'MIT'
  s.author           = { "me" => "me@me.com" }
  s.source           = { :git => "https://github.com/me/MyLib.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.dependency 'Alamofire'

  s.source_files = 'MyLib/**/*.swift', 'MySubLib/**/*.swift'
  s.resource_bundles = {
  }

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`subspec`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec). I use it in my framework [L10n-swift](https://github.com/Decybel07/L10n-swift).

> A library can specify a dependency on either another library, a
>   subspec of another library, or a subspec of itself.

Going back to your problem

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name             = "MyLib"
    s.version          = "0.1"
    s.summary          = ""

    s.description      = <<-DESC

    DESC

    s.homepage         = "https://github.com/me/MyLib"
    s.license          = 'MIT'
    s.author           = { "me" => "me@me.com" }
    s.source           = { :git => "https://github.com/me/MyLib.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }

    s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
    s.requires_arc = true

    s.subspec 'MySubLib' do |mySubLib|
        mySubLib.dependency 'Alamofire'
        mySubLib.source_files = 'MySubLib/**/*.swift'
    end

    s.subspec 'MyLib' do |myLib|
        myLib.dependency 'MyLib/MySubLib'
        myLib.source_files = 'MyLib/**/*.swift'
    end

    s.resource_bundles = { }
end
```

---

You can also define [`default_subspec`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#default_subspecs)

> An array of subspecs names that should be used as preferred
>   dependency. If not specified a specifications requires all its
>   subspecs as dependencies.

Comment: It doesn't look as if the `MySubLib` subspec is used as a dependency anywhere. Also, why does `MyLib` need its own subspec?

Comment: @Awesome-o Ohh sorry, I made a mistake. Of course, `MyLib` shouldn't depend on itself, but from `MySubLib`. I updated my answer

Comment: I'm not currently working on the thing this was relevant for, but when I get back to it in the near future I'll test this out and mark it as the answer if it works 